# Mongo w/ Mongoose on Express connection closes

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

My connection to my mongo database will close or timeout if left in active. I'm getting the following error when I leave my app in active "no open connections"

My mongo DB is running in a replication set up on AWS.  I'm using the following options when connecting using mongoose.  I'm unsure if any other flags should be set. I was basing my options on teh monodo node driver doc @ http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/server.html.Users will be in my applicaiton for 8+ hours at a time and I don't want anything to timout when they go to lunch or leave for a meeting.

```
  MongoOptions : {
      user: 'root',
      pass: '********',
        replset: {
            auto_reconnect: true,
            poolSize: 25,
            socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 },
            ssl: true,
            sslCert: fs.readFileSync('./server/config/ssl/mongodb-cert.crt'),
            sslKey: fs.readFileSync('./server/config/ssl/mongodb-cert.key')}
    }

mongoose.connect('mongodb://server.com:27017', config.MongoOptions);
```

[image]

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mongodb-user/$20socketOptions$20$20keepAlive/mongodb-user/zHTXH9NbYzo/VFNJtJmZXfkJ   With ReplicaSet's you have to disable auto_reconnect instead of enabling it (doesn't seem obvious) and use safe true on write commands.  Otherewise the native driver keeps trying to reconnect to the closest server and in the case of a failure doesn't move on to the next one in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection getting closed turned out to be another issue that was causing the problem.

We have a replicate set running w/ SSL and are able to keep the connection up for days using the following config:

```
  MongoOptions : {
      user: 'ssssss',
      pass: 'xxxxxx',
        replset: {
            auto_reconnect: false,
            poolSize: 10,
            socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1  },
            ssl: true,
            sslCert: fs.readFileSync('./server/config/ssl/mongodb-cert.crt'),
            sslKey: fs.readFileSync('./server/config/ssl/mongodb-cert.key')}
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

> connectTimeout: 43200000

that should be good for 12 hours

Comment: I'm going to test this out.    I thought that the timeout was using on the initial conneciton.  replset: {
                auto_reconnect: true,
                poolSize: 25,
                socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 ,  connectTimeoutMS: 86400000,socketTimeoutMS:86400000},

Comment: I found some docs on the 10gen site.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/